# Reconnect from laravel on Mysql seems not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a multitenant application that uses databases, I have some applications that use Postgres and others that use MYSQL.

In Laravel I have a middleware where he picks the email and gets the data from the tenant and a trait that connect, this same function works fine in Postgres but is not working on Mysql I missing something to configure?

This line **dd(DB::select('SELECT * FROM users'));** I'm testing if he pick the data from the other database.

**My middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $email = $request->input('email');

    $companyInfo = [];
    $tenantRepository = new TenantRepository();
    $companyInfo = $tenantRepository->getTenantData($email);
    if (count($companyInfo) == 0) {
        return response()->json(['success' => 0, 'message' => "Não foi possível fazer autenticação"], 200);
    }
    $this->reconnect($companyInfo);
    
    // dd('ENTROU');
    dd(DB::select('SELECT * FROM users'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

**This is my Trait**

```
   public function reconnect($tenantInfo) {

      // Apaga a conexão tenant, forçando o Laravel a voltar suas configurações de conexão para o padrão.
      DB::purge('tenant');

      // Setando os dados da nova conexão.
      Config::set('database.connections.tenant.host', $tenantInfo[0]->db_host);
      Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $tenantInfo[0]->db_name);
      Config::set('database.connections.tenant.username', $tenantInfo[0]->db_username);
      Config::set('database.connections.tenant.password', $tenantInfo[0]->db_password);

      // Conecta no banco
      DB::reconnect('tenant');

      // Testa a nova conexão
      Schema::connection('tenant')->getConnection()->reconnect();

   }
```